# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused error installing jenkins on aws instance

Tags: git, maven, amazon-web-services, curl, jenkins

When i run the curl http://localhost:8080 after running the commands below i get the following error

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Here are the commands

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum install -y git nginx java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel aws-cli
sudo alternatives --config java
sudo wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo yum install -y apache-maven
mvn –v
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
sudo yum install jenkins
sudo service jenkins start
sudo chkconfig --add jenkins
```

Comment: Is Jenkins/Tomcat running?

Comment: How to know that?

Comment: `ps aux | grep jenkins` `ps aux | grep tomcat` for example. Or `service tomcat status` , `service jenkins status` if there are installed as a service (not sure for `status` command on these services)